# endless pages in rails 3?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, will-paginate, pagination

I've tried following railscast 114 and several other links to get endless pages in a rails 3 app ive been building. I'm a beginner and I have followed teachmetocode's twitter replica tutorials. Which method for producing endless pages would work best with this model of application? THanks for any help in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a [good tutorial](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari/wiki/How-To:-Create-Infinite-Scrolling-with-jQuery) and [full source code](https://github.com/fschwahn/endless_page) using JQuery and Rails.